# Codeigniter: How to create a dedicated api which tells if database is down

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, codeigniter, error-handling

I have codeigniter REST full project. Need to configure API to confirm if that database connection is up. If database is up return 200 else if down return 500. I want to share this response to cloudflare load balancer. It will hit my API and get to know if database is up or down.
I tried to override DB_Driver.php to give custom response using try catch but it shows only system message.

I have created an API which checks if db is up and returns 200 OK, but that only works when I am connected to database as soon as I disconnect database it won't hit the API and default response is being send.
I tried to change the Codeigniter DB_Driver.php, connecteddb.php but no luck there.

This is my checkDatabase API function code:

```
if(!$this->db) {
        $responseArr = array('data' => 'Database Connection Error');
        $this->set_response($responseArr, REST_Controller::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    } else {
        $responseArr = array('data' => 'Database Connection Active');
        $this->set_response($responseArr, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Can you guys help me out with this?
Thank you.

Comment: I believe you're overthinking this too much. Why not set up a method that makes a simple query, the result of which will always be predictable? You can run that query as often as you'd like and if the model responds anything unexpected (such as `null`, `false`, etc) or you get a database error, use the output class to respond with a 50x code, otherwise respond with a 200 code. I know it's not the most elegant way, but I've done it for years (get the latest ID for a table that will never be empty) and it works like a charm

Comment: What error you are facing when db not connected !!  Did you try with db_debug false in database.php

Comment: @JavierLarroulet, Why not set up a method that makes a simple query, the result of which will always be predictable? I have set up an controller which handles but when database is down codeigniter won't bother to hit the API it returns right away from db_error and shows default error message. that's the problem I'm facing. So how to make that method can you show me some code or way to do that? where should I create that file?

Comment: @BoominathanElango I'm facing default database connection error. with some html in it.
that is **Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.**
Yes I tried with db_debug false but that even won't let me hit my DB status checking API. Somehow I won't to override that response with my json response.